# R creating a new column from unique rows (hashing a column)

Tags: r, transformation

I have a dataframe like

```
id          val
3243        A
3420        B
8428        A
3420        C
9000        D
```

I want to create a new column based on unique ids sequentially, such that

```
 id        val          transformed_id
 3243         A                   1
 3420         B                   2
 8428         A                   3
 3420         C                   2
 9000         D                   4
```

I am really clueless about this, I looked `transform` and `unique`, can think a solution in python but cannot transform that to R.

Comment: provide the output of `dput(df)`, so that we could check easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` or `factor`.

We `match` the 'id' column with the `unique` elements of 'id' to get the numeric index.

```
 df1$transformed_id <- match(df1$id, unique(df1$id))
```

Or we convert the 'id' to `factor` class specifying the `levels` as `unique` values of the 'id' (in this case it should work without specifying the `levels`, but in general specifying the `levels` would be more correct) and convert to `numeric`.

```
 df1$transformed_id <- as.numeric(factor(df1$id, levels=unique(df1$id)))
 df1
 #    id val transformed_id
 #1 3243   A              1
 #2 3420   B              2
 #3 8428   A              3
 #4 3420   C              2
 #5 9000   D              4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(3243L, 3420L, 8428L, 3420L, 9000L),
val = c("A", 
"B", "A", "C", "D")), .Names = c("id", "val"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Good to know use of match and unique here. But it is better to use sort to wrap unique.

Comment: @ShenglinChen  If you use `sort` the order will be different.  I guess the OP wanted it in the same order as in the data